# How to run a loop in all directories inside a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, directory-structure

Let's say I have a directory called `/tmp/main`
and inside it I have 100 other directories .

I want to run a loop through each directory of those directories, for example to make a file with `touch test.txt`

How do I tell the script to process the first, the second, the third and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple loop would work:

```bsh
for dir in /tmp/main/*/; do
    touch "$dir"/test.txt
done
```

The `/` at the end of the pattern `/tmp/main/*/` guarantees that if the pattern matches anything, it will match a directory.

In `bash`, you may want to set the `nullglob` shell option with `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop to ensure that the loop doesn't run at all if the pattern doesn't match anything.  Without `nullglob` set, the loop would still run once with the pattern unexpanded in `$dir`. Another way to fix that would be to make sure that `$dir` is actually a directory before calling `touch`:

```bsh
for dir in /tmp/main/*/; do
    if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
        touch "$dir"/test.txt
    fi
done
```

or, equivalently,

```bsh
for dir in /tmp/main/*/; do
    [ -d "$dir" ] && touch "$dir"/test.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find`:

```
find /tmp/main -type d -exec touch {}/test.txt \;
```

And if you would like to exclude the `/tmp/main` folder from being returned in the results of `find` use:

```
find /tmp/main ! -path /tmp/main -type d -exec touch {}/test.txt \;
```

or

```
find /tmp/main -mindepth 1 -type d -exec touch {}/test.txt \;
```